# Integration local AD with Exchange Online Plan 1

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchangeonline, office365

Help me, I want to know if Exchange Online Plan 1 could integrate with a local AD (like Office 365 with the Azure AD using AD Connect).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do both

1.) You can configure Exchange Online Plan 1 without DirSync / Azure AD Connect. You would manually need to create all users in Exchange Online. Without DirSync / Azure AD Connect users would have to manage two different sets of credentials. One set for their local network and one set for Exchange Online. (Called "Cut over Migration" as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cutover-migration-to-Office-365-9496e93c-1e59-41a8-9bb3-6e8df0cd81b4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874016(v=exchg.150).aspx))

2.) You can configure DirSync (start [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/denotation/2012/11/21/installing-and-configure-dirsync-with-ou-level-filtering-for-office365/)) / Azure AD Connect to sync your local AD with your Exchange Online environment.

Note (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx)):

> If you are using Azure Active Directory DirSync, the maximum number of
>   distribution group members that you can synchronize from your
>   on-premises Active Directory to Azure Active Directory is 15,000. If
>   you are using Azure AD Connect, that number is 50,000.

Comment: As a note: DirSync has been deprecated and has been replaced with Azure AD Connect.